# Issue getting parsing this regex

Tags: regex

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð,.'-]+$/u;
```

Not sure how to include this as one string to run check on?

I think I have to escape the quote but I am not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: JS regex does not support `/u` modifier.

Comment: I think I have to escape the quote but I am not quite sure how to do it. I am not very good with regex.

Comment: You do not have to escape any quote inside a JS regex literal.

Comment: Thanks, I just removed the /u modifier at the end works now

Comment: Try this instead `var regex = /^[a-zA-Z\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u00E4\u00E3\u00E5\u0105\u010D\u0107\u0119\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u00EB\u0117\u012F\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u00EF\u0142\u0144\u00F2\u00F3\u00F4\u00F6\u00F5\u00F8\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u00FC\u0173\u016B\u00FF\u00FD\u017C\u017A\u00F1\u00E7\u010D\u0161\u017E\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u00C4\u00C3\u00C5\u0104\u0106\u010C\u0116\u0118\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u00CB\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u00CF\u012E\u0141\u0143\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u00D6\u00D5\u00D8\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u00DC\u0172\u016A\u0178\u00DD\u017B\u0179\u00D1\u00DF\u00C7\u0152\u00C6\u010C\u0160\u017D\u2202\u00F0,.'-]+$/;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript regex engine does not support `/u` modifier.

Moreover, you do not have to escape any single or double quote inside a regex literal.

Thus, you can make this regex work bybjust removing the nonsupported modifier:

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð,.'-]+$/;
```